# Should org.joda.time.DateTimeZone be declared as static field in a class instead of creating new instance each time

Tags: java, static, jodatime

Should `org.joda.time.DateTimeZone` be defined as `static` in a class instead of creating a new instance each time it's needed, specially when we're always using the same time zone.

`DateTimeZone` is thread-safe and immutable so it does not make sense to create a new instance each time. Is my thinking correct?

To add more details, currently my class creates a `DateTimeZone` object in the constructor of my class, always for the same time zone, so I thought why not make it static instead of creating a new object each time.

Comment: It **can** be. I will never say that it **should** be without knowing all the details.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I added more details in the question, could you please comment now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you can create is as a `static` field - and the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) in [@Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44763394/7605325) tells you about the possible drawbacks of doing so (like possible problems if you want to test your code in a different timezone and so on).

But if your concerns are about performance and memory usage, I wouldn't worry too much about that. It seems that Joda-Time uses an internal cache of `DateTimeZone` objects:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
DateTimeZone other = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
System.out.println(zone == other); // true
```

The code above prints `true`, which means that both are the same object.

Of course this is an implementation detail (I'm using **Joda-Time 2.9.9**) and it's not good to rely on such details as these things can change.

Anyway, if you're sure that this timezone will never change, you can make it `static`. If there's a possibility of having more than one in the future, don't (I wouldn't).

Comment: thanks for your answer Hugo +1 and also for the sharing implementation details, it helps.

Answer (score 3):

> DateTimeZone is thread-safe and immutable, and all subclasses must be as well.

See [api](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html)

So yes. It can be declared as static field.

Should you do it or not, it depends on your class and overall project design. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) why static fields may be evil.